# GetProcessAffinityMask keeps returning 0xffff

Tags: c

I'm learning how to use GetProcessAffinityMask to make a scheduler for an school assignment. Right now whenever I call the function like so:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    DWORD_PTR proc_aff = 0;
    DWORD_PTR sys_aff = 0;

    GetProcessAffinityMask(GetCurrentProcess(), &proc_aff, &sys_aff);

    printf("pmask: %#6.4x\n",proc_aff);
    printf("smask: %#6.4x",sys_aff);

}
```

This output is:

```
pmask: 0xffff
smask: 0xffff
```

I'm not sure why but I feel like this shouldn't be the output. It doesn't look like the output from my assignment(I know it wont match exactly). What could the result be telling me and if it is wrong how do I fix it? I'm running on windows 10 OS with a x64 based processor if that helps.

Comment: What does [GetLastError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror) return?

Comment: Not sure, but will you need admin rights to call that functions?

Comment: I'm not sure if I used it right but its returning 126. Which I think means LoadLibrary Error? Does that make sense? I called it like so: printf("Error: %d",GetLastError()); I also tried running the cmd prompt as admin which gave the same code.